# Appended nodes not formatted

Tags: php, xml, dom, dom-node

I made a PHP script that updates an existing XML file by adding new nodes. The problem is that the new nodes are not formatted. They are written in a single line. Here is my code :

```
$file = fopen('data.csv','r');
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('data.xml'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$root = $xpath->query('/my/node');
$root = $root->item(0);
$root = $xml->importNode($root,true);

// all the tags created in this loop are not formatted, and written in a single line
while($line=fgetcsv($file,1000,';')){
    $tag = $xml->createElement('cart');
    $tag->setAttribute('attr1',$line[0]);
    $tag->setAttribute('attr2',$line[1]);
    $root->appendChild($tag);
}
$xml->appendChild($root);
$xml->save('updated.xml');
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;` to DOMDocument object where is file stored.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('data.xml'));
$doc->formatOutput = true;

...
```

[PHP.net - DOMDocument::preserveWhiteSpace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace)

Comment: Answer updated. I'm sorry, I called it on wrong DOM object. Set `preserveWhiteSpace = false` on object where you loaded file (I thinkg it should be before loading) and you should be fine.